# Rounding value half-up to 2 decimal places in Go

Tags: go, rounding

Rounding positive value (example here: 1.015) half-up to 2 decimal places using `math.Round()` in Go:

```
fmt.Println(math.Round(1.015*100) / 100)
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UPUFCUbIbTi)

I got: `1.02`. That's correct.

But when I employed a function to do the same job:

```
func RoundHalfUp(x float64) float64 {
    return math.Round(x*100) / 100
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/w6yA29y9LTS)

I got `1.01`.

What's wrong with the `RoundHalfUp` function?

Comment: See https://play.golang.org/p/UVuNExG9XiL.  The expression `1.015*100` is a [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions) and is evaluated exactly.  The expression `x*100` is evaluated using float64s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)
>
> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do
>   not overflow.
>
> Implementation restriction: Although numeric constants have arbitrary
>   precision in the language, a compiler may implement them using an
>   internal representation with limited precision. That said, every
>   implementation must:
>
> - Represent floating-point constants, including the parts of a    complex constant, with a mantissa of at least 256 bits and a signed
>     binary exponent of at least 16 bits.
> - Round to the nearest representable constant if unable to represent    a floating-point or complex constant due to limits on    precision.
>
> These requirements apply both to literal constants and to the result
>   of evaluating constant expressions.
>
> [Constant expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions)
>
> Constant expressions may contain only constant operands and are
>   evaluated at compile time.
>
> Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly; intermediate values
>   and the constants themselves may require precision significantly
>   larger than supported by any predeclared type in the language.
>
> Implementation restriction: A compiler may use rounding while
>   computing untyped floating-point or complex constant expressions; see
>   the implementation restriction in the section on constants. This
>   rounding may cause a floating-point constant expression to be invalid
>   in an integer context, even if it would be integral when calculated
>   using infinite precision, and vice versa.

---

Implement the `RoundHalfUp` function like the Go compiler does for `math.Round(1.015*100) / 100`. `1.015*100` is a untyped floating-point constant expression. Use the `math/big` package with at least 256 bits of precision. Go `float64` (IEEE-754 64-bit floating-point) has 53 bits of precision.

For example, with 256 bits of precision (constant expression),

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/big"
)

func RoundHalfUp(x string) float64 {
    // math.Round(x*100) / 100
    xf, _, err := big.ParseFloat(x, 10, 256, big.ToNearestEven)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    xf100, _ := new(big.Float).Mul(xf, big.NewFloat(100)).Float64()
    return math.Round(xf100) / float64(100)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(RoundHalfUp("1.015"))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/uqtYwP4o22B

Output:

```
1.02
```

---

If we only use 53 bits of precision (`float64`):

```
xf, _, err := big.ParseFloat(x, 10, 53, big.ToNearestEven)
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ejz-wkuycaU

Output:

```
1.01
```